# Executing ViewController's methods from UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, uinavigationcontroller

I have created several ViewControllers in a storyboard that each have their own class files.  In AppDelegate I have programatically generated a UINavigationController that exists at the top of the app for every page.  This will have two buttons that will be the same for every ViewController, one will load a ViewController called 'settings' and one will fire a method that reveals a side menu.

Screen shots to illustrate:

[image: Button to reveal the menu underneath]
[image: Current ViewController slid across to reveal the menu]

Currently, each ViewController has a button in the top left, that when pressed moves the current ViewController across revealing the menu below.

This works fine but what I want is for this button to be removed and replaced with the button that is on the NavigationController (currently place holder menu button seen in the purple NavigationController).

How do I implement the code that moves the ViewController in the AppDelegate, what the UINavigationController is generated?

AppDelegate.m

```
@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    MainViewController* mainVC = [mainStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    UINavigationController *navVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainVC];

    [mainVC setTitle:@"Congress app"];

    UIBarButtonItem *showSettingsButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(showSettings:)];
    UIBarButtonItem *showMenuButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menuButton.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(revealMenu:)];

    mainVC.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = showMenuButton;
    mainVC.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = showSettingsButton;

    [self.window setRootViewController:navVC];

    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
- (IBAction)revealMenu:(id)sender
{
    // This obviously won't work but what should go here instead?
    // Something like get instance of MainViewController and fire it's reveal menu
    // method but passing the current ViewController Id and running slidingViewController anchorTopViewTo:ECRight on that?
    [self.slidingViewController anchorTopViewTo:ECRight];
}
```

MainViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];  

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.75f;
    self.view.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0f;
    self.view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

    if (![self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController isKindOfClass:[MenuViewController class]]) {
        self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MenuVC"];
    }

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.slidingViewController.panGesture];

    self.menuBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
     _menuBtn.frame = CGRectMake(8, 80, 34, 24);
    [_menuBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menuButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_menuBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(revealMenu:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view addSubview:self.menuBtn];
    NSLog(@"MainVC loaded");
}
- (IBAction)revealMenu:(id)sender
{
    [self.slidingViewController anchorTopViewTo:ECRight];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're better off not doing that...

1. This isn't app delegate responsibility
2. There are 3rd party implementations on github / CocoaControls which offer this and manage the navigation bar

It is much better to rework your current view hierarchy than to force a connection from the app delegate.

- The responsibility of the app delegate is to respond to app level events (like foreground / background notifications). It might be involved in setting up the initial UI but other than that is should do basically nothing.

Comment: I see what you mean but this seems like such a simple thing to implement - a button that took the current ViewController and run one of it's methods.  I guess I am missing something fairly fundamental.

Comment: Not really, using a 3rd party controller like https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController will save you time and result in a better app design. You shouldn't have the slide functionality in each view controller...

Comment: I am actually using that 3rd party controller (ECSlidingViewController).  The tutorial that it came with actually showed the slider functionality being used in each VC.  I added the NavigationController to act as a static menu throughout the app.

Comment: So the button should be connecting to ECSlidingViewController, not the app delegate.

Comment: The buttons works fine (as per the tutorial) if I leave the button on each ViewController but instead of one button on each VC I want one button on the UINavigationControl instead.  Since the UINC is built in the AppDelegate, it seemed logical to add this button there.

Comment: No, because the view controllers each have a navigation item which is pushed onto the nav bar. So the buttons should be added there, or in a nav controller delegate.

Comment: So, for each VC would I create a button and insert it into the UINC?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45482/discussion-between-wain-and-ryan)